# Upgrading GlassFish 3.1.2.2 to use JSF 2.2

Tags: jpa, jsf-2, glassfish-3

I am working with GlassFish 3.1.2.2 and I can not upgrade to 4 due to OS restrictions. I'm interested in upgrading JPA 2.0 to JPA 2.1 and JSF 2.1 to JSF 2.2 in GlassFish 3.1.2.2. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak for JPA, but for JSF it's a matter of replacing `javax.faces.jar` file in its `/modules` directory by the desired version. Don't forget to clean the GlassFish cache and work folders before deploying, because the older JSF version may still hang in there and then cause conflicts.

Comment: thanks for your prompt answer and for editing my question to be more clear.
I hope any body help me by answering the JPA part of this question